# How to add swift package to TemplateInfo.plist?

Tags: xcode, templates, swift-package-manager

I want to link a `Swift Package Manager` package with my Xcode Template in its `TemplateInfo.plist` file

which is in Xcode UI located here
[image: SPM]

I see that in `project.pbxproj` it looks like

```
/* Begin XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference section */
        255340AE243903CF00EFC2D2 /* XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference "UIKitPlus" */ = {
            isa = XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference;
            repositoryURL = "https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/UIKitPlus";
            requirement = {
                kind = upToNextMajorVersion;
                minimumVersion = 1.18.0;
            };
        };
/* End XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference section */
/* Begin XCSwiftPackageProductDependency section */
        255340AF243903CF00EFC2D2 /* UIKitPlus */ = {
            isa = XCSwiftPackageProductDependency;
            package = 255340AE243903CF00EFC2D2 /* XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference "UIKitPlus" */;
            productName = UIKitPlus;
        };
/* End XCSwiftPackageProductDependency section */
```

And I'm trying to find a way how to add it into `TemplateInfo.plist` to have it pre-added into my new projects.

Comment: Trying to figure out same thing.  All info I have seen only shows adding a file or adding code to existing files.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am stuck with SPM. I have successfully tried cocoapods but I want to integrate with SPM.

Comment: @LovinaHajirawala I haven't seen any solution yet. Please also ping me if you find something.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `TemplateInfo.plist` file and add a new key-value pair under the Options key with the following structure:

**key**: dependencies

**value**: an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a Swift Package.

```
<key>dependencies</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>package</key>
    <string>https://github.com/YourPackage</string>
    <key>version</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
  </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Can you share a full `TemplateInfo.plist` file for Xcode 14? No combination of this key-value actually adds the dependency to the new project. For example: https://github.com/joemasilotti/TurboNativeXcodeTemplate/pull/5

Comment: @Spacehead Please share the full `TemplateInfo.plist` with swift package manager dependencies